# Sorting a two-dimensional array by columns

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, bubble-sort

I have a task to sort the columns of two-dimensional array. I thought of using a bubble-sorting algorithm and then implemented it. But I have the last column unsorted. Can somebody help me?

```
array = [
  [23,32,6,7,2],
  [17,10,56,48,11],
  [10,9,24,42,31],
  [15,17,98,12,3],
  [2,5,1,5,7]
]
```

```
def bubble_sort array
  new_array = array.transpose
  num = new_array.length
  loop do
    sorted = false
    (num-1).times do |i|
      (num-1).times do |j|
        if new_array[i][j] > new_array[i][j+1]
          new_array[i][j], new_array[i][j+1] = new_array[i][j+1], new_array[i][j]
          sorted = true
        end
      end
    end
    break if not sorted
  end
  return new_array.transpose
end
```

Then the output is:

```
2   5   1   5   2
10  9   6   7   11
15  10  24  12  31
17  17  56  42  3
23  32  98  48  7
```

I tried to change the number of times in the loop but it did not help me.

Comment: Do you have to implement your own sorting? If not you can simply transpose the Array then sort the sub arrays and then transpose back e.g. `array.transpose.each(&:sort!).transpose`

Comment: Yes, i should implement own

Comment: As a follow-up to @engineersmnky's advice, you wish to do the following: `arr.transpose.map { |a| my_sort(a) }.transpose`. If you need to write your own sort routine, fine, but make it a separate method (e.g., `my_sort`). There are two reasons for doing so: your code is easier to read and easier to test. Regarding the latter, you will want to demonstrate that `my_sort` and a built-in `sort` give the same results for a test suite. You can't do that cleanly if the sorting code is part of a larger method. This really is two questions.

Comment: You want those rows sorted by their last value?

Comment: While i agree with other commentators here, your code will work fine if you change  `(num-1).times do |i|`  to `num.times do |i|` since you have `num` columns.

Comment: @PavelOganesyan thanks a lot! It was quite a stupid mistake so now it works! :)